# Getting the 404 error occasionally for the wordpress post page

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting the strange bug on post page, When I click post link from the posts page, am getting the 404 error occasionally. Some times it will load exact post and some times it will return 404 error

The most other scenarios are:-

Mobile devices :- 65% of the time am getting the 404 error for few posts and when I copy paste the original link on the browser directly, it will load without any issue.

Desktop:- 30-55 % of time getting the 404 error for few posts and when I copy paste the original link on the browser directly, it will load without any issue. Also whenever I am getting this issue, will work fine after a refresh/reload.( Checked the post link manually and its correctly listed on posts page)

Note: I am using the custom permalink structure (using post name in url instead of post id)

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: We would need more information to try to help you.  The URL, some screenshots showing snapshots of each step of your process, with circles and arrows, etc.

Comment: @aparente001, Thanks fro your consideration. As I said its a strange bug. Will explain you bit more. I have a posts page that contains  0 - 20 post links and these links are rewritten using custom permalinks [link](/%postname%). when I click on those links, it will lead to the post detail page(article page). But occasionally the same page will return as 404. Meanwhile If I copy and paste the  link directly to the browser it will load without an issue. This occurs occasionally on pc and regularly on mobile devices. Have checked the header details and not found any issue

Answer (score 0):

This is due to same slug for both post type and page.

To remove 404 error, post type slug and page slug should not be matched.

Make it different.

Example:post_type:contact and page-slug:contactus.

This may work,try it.

Upvote if worked.